# Document certification/signing on top of blockchain

Tags: hash, cryptography, digital-signature, bitcoin, blockchain

I am currently experimenting with signing documents on top of Blockchain (MultiChain).

I want to make sure that a certain document's content

1. Was issued without doubt by a certain party (that owns a private key)
2. Was issued at a given point in time
3. Was never modified

My approach would be to just hash the document and put the hash as metadata (after OP_RETURN) in a Blockchain transaction. With Blockchain, the transaction content is signed by an organization's private key.

Does this approach alone fulfill all three conditions mentioned above?

There's a project from MIT (http://certificates.media.mit.edu/), but they put a signed document hash on the Blockchain instead of just putting the document hash itself on the Blockchain.

Comment: whenever a document is issued will it be put in the blockchain?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with a documents' hash, as long as you can provide non-repudiation. Of course you must be able to track the hash to its original document, timestamping...etc. I don´t have much experience with bitcoin blockchain, but signing a hash is way better that working with the document itself in some situations, yours appears to be one of them.